# Getting one char from specified position

Tags: string, coronasdk

I'd to reach a char from a string in corona. Basically I want to:

```
local mystr = "corona"
print( mystr[3] )
```

But it always returns nil.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to iterate individual characters in Lua string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829063/how-to-iterate-individual-characters-in-lua-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple logic that I used for the same purpose. Hope this may help you:

```
local mystr   = "corona"
local str_tbl = {}
for i=1,string.len (mystr) do
    str_tbl[i] = mystr:sub(i, i)
    print("Character in position "..i.."is:"..str_tbl[i])
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I think mystr[3] is like mystr:sub(3,3)