# My Lua code utilizing my CPU on 100%

Tags: lua

I want to replace utf8 html entities in html sources with real characters. I have the "entities" replacement table which is traversed with code bellow. If I run this code it utilizes my CPU up to 100%.

Please could you help me how to rewrite first loop in better way? I understand that in Lua strings are immutable so I think there are many copies of data variable and this could be the reason.

```
local entities = {
    {["char"]="!", ["utf"]="&#33;"},
    {["char"]='"', ["utf"]="&#34;"},
    {["char"]="#", ["utf"]="&#35;"},
    {["char"]="$", ["utf"]="&#36;"},
    {["char"]="%", ["utf"]="&#37;"},
    {["char"]="&", ["utf"]="&#38;"},
    {["char"]="'", ["utf"]="&#39;"},
    -- +312 rows more
}    

local function clear_text(data)
    for _, e in ipairs(entities) do
        data = string.gsub(data, e.utf, e.char)
    end
    return data
end

-- this is just for testing ... replacement in many html sources
for i=1,200 do
    local data = some_html_page_source()
    clear_text(data)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: misread question, so rewrote it with the same principle.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829063/how-to-iterate-individual-characters-in-lua-string), you can use `str:gsub(pattern, function)` to perform a custom replacement on all matches of `pattern` inside `str`.

The pattern `&#.+;` should match all utf characters, calling `function` for each of the matches.

All that is left to do in the callback `function` is to find the matching human-readable `char`, and returning that as the replacing value. To this end, it would be faster if `entities` was keyed by the `utf` strings, with their respective `char` as value, so you don't have to iterate `entities` every time.

another edit: according to the [lua documentation on gsub](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/string/gsub.html), the second parameter can be a table. In that case, the lookup is done automatically and it will attempt to use each match as the key, replacing it with the value from that table. That would be the cleanest solution once you restructure `entities`

Comment: But that's backwards. You want the utf value to be the key. And those take multiple characters.

Comment: Indeed. I completely misread the question. This does make it trickier, but you could still use the same principle.

Comment: Give me a moment to read up on lua's pattern matching, since it is not standard regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Lua 5.3 required
local html_entities = {
   nbsp = " ",
   lt = "<",
   gt = ">",
   amp = "&",
   euro = "€",
   copy = "©",
   Gamma = "Γ",
   Delta = "Δ",
   prod = "∏",
   sum = "∑",
   forall = "∀",
   exist = "∃",
   empty = "∅",
   nabla = "∇",
   isin = "∈",
   notin = "∉",
   -- + many more rows
}


local str = [[&exist; &euro; &empty; &Delta; &#8364; &#x20AC;]]

str = str:gsub("&(#?)(.-);",
   function(prefix, name)
      if prefix ~= "" then
         return utf8.char(tonumber("0"..name))
      else
         return html_entities[name]
      end
   end
)

print(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another way of replacing the sequence of characters.

```
local function clear_text(data)
    return (string.gsub(
        data,
        [=[[!"#$%&']]=],  -- all your entries goes here, between [=[  and  ]=]
        function(c)
            return "&#" .. string.byte(c) .. ";"  -- replace with char code
        end
    ))
end

-- this is just for testing ... replacement in many html sources
for i=1,200 do
    local data = "!#!#!#!#!#!";
    print(clear_text(data))
end
```