# How do I iterate over characters in a string?

Tags: string, moonscript

In moonscript, how can I iterate over characters in a string?

I tried iterating as if the string was a table, but that did not work:

```
s = "hello"
for c in *s
  print c
```

Answer (score 2):

Following [lua equivalents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/829063/2038264):

**Iterate by index and substring**

```
s = "hello"
for i = 1, #s
  print s\sub(i, i)
```

**Iterate using pattern matching**

```
s = "hello"
for c in s\gmatch"."
  print c
```

For unicode strings, you can use:

```
s = "✅✈♛"
for _, c in utf8.codes(s)
  print utf8.char(c)
```